# Incorrect time shown in Google LineChart

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, datetime, google-visualization

There are dates stored as `timestamp` in the MySQL database. If I view them with `phpMyAdmin` the correct time is shown. In a `php` script I try to output the date with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` into a `Javascript Date Object` (`new Date()`). When displaying the data in a `Google Chart` there is a time offset of `+2:00` hours (my current timezone). I also looked into the timestamp and a timestamp converter told me that the local time is correct and UTC time is `-2:00` hours.

In the php-script I already set the timezone with `date_default_timezone_set()`. `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;` outputs `SYSTEM`. But I still get the time offset. Now I use

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONVERT_TZ(Timestamp, "+02:00", @@session.time_zone)) ...
```

and I get the correct data. Does this mean that the data is stored with a 2 hours offset? Why does `phpMyAdmin` showing me the correct date and time? Or does the Google chart expects UTC time and the browser automatically adds the difference for the timezone?

What is the real problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Now I wrote a function which converts the timestamp from the database into an UTC date:

```
function getDateinUTC(timestamp){
    var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
    var year    = date.getUTCFullYear();
    var month   = date.getUTCMonth() + 1; // getMonth() is zero-indexed, so we'll increment to get the correct month number
    var day     = date.getUTCDate();
    var hours   = date.getUTCHours();
    var minutes = date.getUTCMinutes();
    var seconds = date.getUTCSeconds();

    return new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds);
}
```

When I create the `DataTable` I simply call the function as shown here:

```
rows: [
    {c:[{v:getDateinUTC(stamp)}, {v: value}]},
]
```

You have to replace `stamp` and `value` with your php-code which fills the place.

This idea is based on the article [Automatic timezone conversion in JavaScript](https://blog.serverdensity.com/automatic-timezone-conversion-in-javascript/) by David Mytton.

So far the times seems to be correct.